# Calculating the derivative of $\csc^2(4x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am having problems calculating derivatives of squared trigonometric functions.

$$f(x) = \csc^2(4x)$$

Let's see... This is equivalent to

$$f(x) = \csc(4x)\cdot \csc(4x)$$

Now, to get the derivative, we use the product rule:

$$f'(x) = 2 \cdot (-\csc(4x)\cdot\cot(4x)\cdot\csc(4x))$$

But this appears to be wrong when I evaluate this in a calculator. What is the problem with this procedure?

Comment: You need to use the chain rule for the $4x$ as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$y=(f(ax))^2$$
$$y'=2f(ax)f'(ax)(a)$$

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easier to write $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sin^{2}(4x)}$$ so that $$\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\frac{-1}{\sin^{4}(4x)}\cdot(\sin^{2}(4x))'\\
&=\frac{-2\sin(4x)\cos(4x)\cdot4}{\sin^{4}(4x)}\\
&=\frac{-8\cos(4x)}{\sin^{3}(4x)}\\
&=-8\cot(4x)\csc^{2}(4x)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice, Applying chain rule as follows $$\frac{d}{dx}(\csc^2 (4x) )=\frac{d}{dx}(\csc (4x) )^2$$$$=2\csc (4x)\frac{d}{dx}(\csc (4x))$$ $$=2\csc(4x)(-\csc(4x)\cot(4x))\frac{d}{dx}(4x)$$$$=2\csc(4x)(-\csc(4x)\cot(4x))(4)$$
$$=\color{red}{-8\csc^2(4x)\cot(4x)}$$